# Avoid exceptions when parsing enum value from string?

Tags: c#, .net

In this example:

```
try
{
    this.myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), queryStringKeyValue);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    this.myEnum = null;
}
```

How to avoid the introduced dependency on catching a generic exception? I'm getting no clues from ReSharper. Ideally, I'd like to get rid of the try / catch.

Comment: `this.myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), queryStringKeyValue);`

There, I got rid of the try/catch for you.

Comment: Note that the Enum type is a non-nullable value type, thus the code in your catch block will not actually compile, unless you have specified that the type of the `this.myEnum` member is `MyEnum?`, which is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<MyEnum>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, the TryParse methods return a boolean on failure instead of throwing an exception. But also, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx. It lists the Exceptions that may be thrown, so rather than catching the generic Exception, you could catch the specific exceptions being thrown like ArgumentException. The example on that page shows catching ArgumentException.

Comment: Completely overlooked TryParse. That's the way.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I wasn't the first to suggest it. Up vote the others. They said it before me.

Answer (score 5):

Try looking at [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

> TryParse(Of TEnum)(String, TEnum) is identical to the Parse(Type, String) method, except that instead of throwing an exception, it returns false if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need for exception handling when parsing the string representation of an enumeration value.

Answer (score 4):

You can eliminate the exception by using `Enum.TryParse()`, e.g.

```
MyEnum myEnum;
if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(queryStringKeyValue, out myEnum))
{
    // successfully parsed enum
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing a nice example of real-world usage and a pattern that can be applied to many `TryParse` situations. A reference link would be nice, however.

Answer (score 4):

Use Enum.TryParse() instead.  It returns a boolean value to indicate success or failure, and it's generic so it also saves you the juggling with casting.

```
bool success = Enum.TryParse(queryStringKeyValue, out this.myEnum);
```

Also, you shouldn't be able to assign null to an enumeration, assuming that field isn't actually of type `MyEnum?`.